# Append multiple header information fields to file until next header found

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, sed

I am attempting to parse many log files using bash. The log files look something like this:

```
"",1/8/2016
"Timezone",-6

"Serial No.","000001"
"Location:","LS_trap_2c"
"High temperature limit (�C)",-20
"Low temperature limit (�C)",-40
"Date - Time","Temperature (�C)"
"8/11/2015 12:00",28.0
"8/11/2015 14:00",28.5
"8/11/2015 16:00",24.0

"",1/8/2016
"Timezone",-6

"Serial No.","000002"
"Location:","LS_trap_2D"
"High temperature limit (�C)",-20
"Low temperature limit (�C)",-40
"Date - Time","Temperature (�C)"
"8/11/2015 12:00",28.0
"8/11/2015 14:00",28.5
```

I want to append the Serial no., and Location (and maybe others later on)  onto each line until the next header is reached, and output this to a `master.csv` file. The file should look like this ultimately:

```
"",1/8/2016
"Timezone",-6

"Serial No.","000001"
"Location:","Trap_2c"
"High temperature limit (�C)",-20
"Low temperature limit (�C)",-40
"Date - Time","Temperature (�C)"
LS_trap_2c,000001,"8/11/2015 12:00",28.0
LS_trap_2c,000001,"8/11/2015 14:00",28.5
LS_trap_2c,000001,"8/11/2015 16:00",24.0

"",1/8/2016
"Timezone",-6

"Serial No.","00002"
"Location:","LS_trap_2D"
"High temperature limit (�C)",-20
"Low temperature limit (�C)",-40
"Date - Time","Temperature (�C)"
LS_trap_2D,00002,"8/11/2015 12:00",28.0
LS_trap_2D,00002,"8/11/2015 14:00",28.5
```

Here is a question that helped me do processing on similar files using bash sed:

[Bash Append header information to each line of a file until next header found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219975/)

This oneliner is great for finding a header, storing it in holdspace and adding it into the front of each line

```
sed -r '/^"/h;//!{G;s/(.*)\n.*"(.*)"/\2,\1/}' fil.csv  >masfil.csv
```

This approach has not worked for appending multiple strings to the front since I am unsure of how to use multiple hold spaces with sed. Also, I'm not  sure if sed is the best way to do this. I'm not very familiar with sed so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

assuming your data is consistent

```
awk -F, '/"Serial No."/ {sn = $2} 
         /"Location:"/  {loc = $2} 
         /"([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"/ 
                        {$0 = loc FS sn FS $0}1' file
```

you can get rid of the quotes as well with `gsub(/"/,"",$2)` when assigning sn and loc, but not sure to remove them since the rest of the fields are quoted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer- evidently my data is not consistent- your awk works with the data I posted, but not with my real data (I thought they were identical). The serial number lengths are different and the location names are varied, but still...it only works with the data posted...Can you point toward a resource for understanding the awk you gave me?

Comment: Your awk works, but only when I copy/paste the data into a new file. I'm thinking this is possibly due to one/multiple carriage return(s), but I'm not sure.

Comment: That exactly what I did : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242852/awk-only-works-on-copied-data-why/42243028#42243028

Answer (score 0):

There is only one hold space in sed, but you don't need multiple in this case:

```
/^"Serial No."/ {       # If we are on the "Serial No." line...
    N                   # Append next line to pattern space
    h                   # Copy pattern space to hold space
    # Remove everything but location and serial number from pattern space
    s/"[^"]*","([^"]*)"\n"[^"]*","([^"]*)"/\1,\2,/
    x                   # Swap pattern space and hold space
}
/^"[[:digit:]]/ {       # We are on a line where we want to prepend our data
    G                   # Append hold space to pattern space
    s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/  # Move hold space content to front of pattern space
}
```

If this is stored in a file `sedscr.sed`, it can be called like

```
sed -E -f sedscr.sed infile
```

This *does* remove the double quotes as show in the example input/output; it also assumes that the lines where the data should be prepended are lines with a date, i.e., starting with a double quote and a digit.